# Error while sending a GET Request to a servlet from android

Tags: java, android, servlets

after searching around im able to retreive a response from my servlet , but i cant send a parameter (a username and a password parameter) from android to a servlet! My logcat shows this error:

```
04-0java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpResponse
at com.example.httpgetandroidexample.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)
at com.example.httpgetandroidexample.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and i cant understand why!
Here it is my android main activity:

```
package com.example.httpgetandroidexample;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

               public TextView content;
                EditText name,pass;
                String URL,nameValue,passValue;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                     name      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                     pass       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                     content       =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

                   Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
                   try {
                    nameValue    =URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                    passValue    =URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login/web";
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                        runner.execute(new String[ ] { URL });
                       }
                      });


   }
            private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                  String response = "";
                  for (String url : urls) {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    try {
                        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = 
                                new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",nameValue));
                            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",passValue));
                            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                    postParameters);
                            ((HttpResponse) httpGet).setEntity(formEntity);
                      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                      String s = "";
                      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                      }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                  return response;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                  content.setText(result);
                }
              }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

UPDATE:

```
now i have changed my android code like this:
package com.example.httpgetandroidexample;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

               public TextView content;
                EditText name,pass;
                String URL;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                     name      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                     pass       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                     content       =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

                   Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
                   try {
                    String nameValue    ="user="+URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String passValue    ="&pass="+URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login/web?"+nameValue+passValue;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                        runner.execute(new String[ ] { URL });
                       }
                      });


   }
            private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                  String response = "";
                  for (String url : urls) {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    try {

                      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                      String s = "";
                      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                      }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                  return response;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                  content.setText(result);
                }
              }
}
```

this time runs without logcat errors but the parameters does not come to the servlet!

Comment: I think you're mixing between HTTP GET and HTTP POST. Choose one or the other but not both. What are you trying to do? I see you are trying to pass in `user` and `pass`.

Comment: im just trying to send 2 parameters(user,pass) to a servlet via GET method and getting a response from the servlet and showing it .I can get a response from the servlet but i cant send the parameters to the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have modified the activity and the problem was that the `URL` and `nameValue` and `passValue` was declared on the wrong section of the code ! Here it is the right android code:

```
package com.example.httpgetandroidexample;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

               public TextView content;
                EditText name,pass;
                String URL,nameValue,passValue;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                     name      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                     pass       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                     content       =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                     content.setText("Vendosni Perdoruesin dhe Fjalekalimin");
                   Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);



                   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           nameValue="&user="+name.getText().toString();
                           passValue    ="&pass="+pass.getText().toString();
                           URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login/web2?activitetiNR=1"+nameValue+passValue;
                        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();

                           Log.i("url",URL);
                           Log.i("url",nameValue);
                           Log.i("url",passValue);
                        runner.execute(new String[ ] { URL });
                       }
                      });


   }
            private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                  String response = "";
                  for (String url : urls) {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    try {

                      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                      String s = "";
                      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                      }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                  return response;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                  content.setText(result);
                }
              }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the stack trace, I guess your problem is at this line.

```
((HttpResponse) httpGet).setEntity(formEntity);
```

Why are you casting it to `HttpResponse`?

OK. You want to send user/pass parameters using HTTP GET. For HTTP GET, all parameters are part of the URL. Maybe this can give you some help on how to perform a HTTP GET and pass parameters in. But in general, URL would look like this

`http://www.blah.com/servlet?user="1234"&pass="password"`

The stuff after the `?` in the URL contains all the parameters. But there is a length limit in the URL, if you exceed that length, you'll have to use HTTP POST.

Try this link to see if it can help you
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_Get_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=63&aaid=88

Comment: because eclipse shows an error if i dont cast it ! it show an error on `setEntity()` method saying `The method setEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity) is undefined for the type HttpGet`

Comment: Sure, HTTP GET requests lack a body, but you can try with HTTP POST instead. Casting an HttpGet request into a response does not make sense.

Comment: If you want to send HTTP POST, instantiate a `HttpPost` and call `setEntity` on it

Comment: thank you for your reply, i updated the android code but i get nothing on the servlet side , and i cant understand why!

Comment: @p3rand0r First thing is to make sure you're sending the correct URL request (ie. Print out the URL). Then check on the servlet side whether the request was received (ie. Tomcat logs). If you have a TCP sniffer (ie. wireshark), put that on and snoop on the LAN interface to see what's actually coming into the server.

Comment: @p3rand0r try accessing your servlet from a browser. This is to ensure your servlet actually works.

Comment: @anonymous i have tried wireshark but its to complicated for me , also i tried to find the tomcatlogs but i just cant find it (no file on log folder in tomcat) also on the browser the servlet works just fine :/